# where I must to put my xml files which I want to use it in my dynamic web project on eclipse?

Tags: javascript, xml, eclipse

I new with xml I read tutorial on (w3schools.com) on xml file I find sample to read and print an xml file this code:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't knew where I must to put my xml file on my dynamic web project on eclipse ? 
in code above the instruction `xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);` 
where I must to put books.xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It purely depends how you do the configuration, but i will provide some ways in which you can follow-

1) You can directly put the `xml` files inside your `webcontent` folder.

[image]
2) If you have more number of `XML files` and you want them to according to there type in one place then you can store it inside some folder `<folder-name>` inside webcontent.[image]

for the second scenario you have to slightly modify the code you are trying to run as below
`xhttp.open("GET", "data/books.xml", true);`

Comment: Thank you so much @Rishal dev singh